# Play-Framework: ClassCastException occured : java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to models.Systems

Tags: java, playframework

I'm attempting to iterate a `List` of objects. like so..

```
for(System s : usersSystems){

}
```

Where `usersSystems` is of type `List<UserSystems>`. `usersSystems` is a fairly simple class simply consisting of a constructor...

```
public UsersSystems(System system,int ID) {
    this.system = system;
    this.ID = ID;
}
```

Assigning `usersSystems` is done by making it equal to `user.sources` which is initialized and given a default value in the `User` constructor. Below is my stacktrace. Why am I getting the above error and how do I correct it?

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to models.Systems
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:227)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to models.Systems
at controllers.Start.starting(Start.java:40)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:540)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:498)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:474)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:469)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:157)
... 1 more
```

**EDIT:**

**UserSystem**

```
@Entity
public class UsersSystem extends Model{

public int ID;
public System system;

public UsersSystem(System system, int ID) {
    this.source = source;
    this.ID = ID;
}

}
```

**SYSTEM**

```
@Entity
 public class System extends Model{

private String name;
private int ID;

public System(String name, int ID){
    this.name = name;
    this.ID = ID;
}

}
```

Comment: You first say that your list holds System instances. Then you tell us that System is a simple class with a constructor, and show us the constructor of a class named UserSystems (and not System). And finally, your list, according to the exception contains LinkedHashMap instances, and tries to cast it to Systems (with a final s). That makes four different types. You seem to be very confused with your types. And without seeing the code which instantiates and populates the list, it's impossible to tell you where the error is.

Comment: @JBNizet Woops! I've clarified my question hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Show us the code. And does System extend UsersSystems, because if it's not, then the code you showed should not even compile?

Comment: @user596186 Please post the code for your models.  Specifically, `System` and `UserSystems`

Comment: You don't show us the code that causes the exception. The first snippet can't compile with these class definitions. And the exception mentions a ClassCastException when trying to cast to models.Systems (with a final s). Show us the code around the line 40 of Start.java.

Answer (score 1):

First off, when using the Play Framework you do not need to specify an ID in your models.  The Play Framework will automatically add the id for you.  Next, you should specify a one-to-one mapping.

Notice, I have also changed the constructor.  I don't know where the `source` variable came from?

```
@Entity
public class UsersSystem extends Model{

  @OneToOne
  public System system;

  public UsersSystem(System system) {
    this.system = system;
  }

}
```

Fields should also be marked public:

```
@Entity
public class System extends Model{

  public String name;

  public System(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

}
```

When iterating over a List, make sure you are using the correct types. 
Now your loop should look like (assuming `usersSystems` is of type `List<UsersSystem>`):

```
for(UsersSystem us : usersSystems){
  System.out.println("The system name is " + us.system.name);
}
```

The Play Framework has good documentation. Check it out at http://www.playframework.org/documentation